# using JQuery to click in a specific X-Y position on a HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to make a auto click on a online game made in a html5 canvas.

In this online game there are 2 canvas overlap each other:

## bg-canvas : background image and static component.

## fg-canvas : some loading, buttons and other staff.

Page has jQuery.
i use google chrome devtool console to inject my code.
first of all i inject a listener for click on #fg-convas and another for #bg-canvas :

```
$("#fg-canvas").on("click",function(e){
  console.log("fg-canvas clicked");
});

$("#bg-canvas").on("click",function(e){
  console.log("bg-canvas clicked");
});
```

after inject this code when i click on canvas i see `fg-canvas clicked` in the console.

And now my problem :

there is a button in this canvas (fg-canvas) that i want to click on it with jquery code . I can get the position of button in canvas with upper listener and then i click on button with this :

```
var e = jQuery.Event( "click");
e.offsetX= ox-10; //ox is the x position i get with listener click
e.offsetY= oy-10; //oy is the y position i get with listener click
$('#fg-canvas').trigger(e);
```

when this code run i can see the listener print `fg-canvas clicked` but the button not clicked!

After this i think maybe i click wrong positions and i change click listener to draw a circle on that position with this code :

```
$("#fg-canvas").on("click",function(e){
  console.log("fg-canvas clicked"); 
  var canvas = document.getElementById('bg-canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = "green";
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
});
```

with this code when click trigger a green circle draw on the button but it not clicked :((

all of my code is :

```
console.log("I AM HERE");
$("body").append('<button style="position:absolute;top:0;" id="test">test</button>');
var ox =0 , oy =0;
$("#fg-canvas").on("click",function(e){
  console.log("fg-canvas clicked");
  var canvas = document.getElementById('bg-canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = "green";
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
});


$("#test").on("click",function(){
  var e = jQuery.Event( "click");
  e.offsetX= ox-10;
  e.offsetY= oy-10;
  console.log(e);
  $('#fg-canvas').trigger(e);
});
```

html code :

```
<div id="canvas-holder" style="height: 900px !important;">
  <canvas id="bg-canvas" width="1200" height="900" dir="rtl" style="z-index:0;width: 1200px; height: 900px;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="fg-canvas" width="1200" height="900" dir="rtl" style="z-index:1;width: 1200px; height: 900px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead to use the **ox** variable you may consider to get the width and height of your canvas dynamically then you can get the center point, just for instance:

```
e.offsetX= $('#fg-canvas').width() / 2;
e.offsetY= $('#fg-canvas').height() / 2;
```

In order to get more help, please add a html fragment.

The snippet:

```js
$("body").append('<button style="position:absolute;top:0;" id="test">test</button>');
var ox =0 , oy =0;
$("#fg-canvas").on("click",function(e){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('bg-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = "green";
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
});


$("#test").on("click",function(){
    var e = jQuery.Event( "click");
    e.offsetX= $('#fg-canvas').width() / 2;
    e.offsetY= $('#fg-canvas').height() / 2;
    $('#fg-canvas').trigger(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="fg-canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="bg-canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: hi . Actually when i simulate the canvases in https://jsfiddle.net/woeful/yLb5dzwc/2/ it's working but i do not underestand why it's not working in that game .

Comment: @Mr.Sun You are right. In order to help you I need more info: console errors, html fragment, and so on. There are many reasons because you get the trouble and where it is necessary to investigate more: js, html, css. With your minimal info I could only create a simple snippet. Thanks for the reply.